# C SSL_Read return 0 bytes

Tags: c, sockets, openssl, tls1.2

I am trying  to send and receive  data through TLS  channel .

***What  is wrong in this Code  ?***

Sample Code   :

```
/* gcc -o sslconnect sslconnect.c -lssl -lcrypto                *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------ */

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- *


 * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
int create_socket(char[], BIO *);

int main() {

  char           dest_url[] ="https://query.yahooapis.com"; 

  BIO              *certbio = NULL;
  BIO               *outbio = NULL;
  X509                *cert = NULL;
  X509_NAME       *certname = NULL;
  const SSL_METHOD *method;
  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  SSL *ssl;
  int server = 0;
  int ret, i;

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
  ERR_load_BIO_strings();
  ERR_load_crypto_strings();
  SSL_load_error_strings();

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * Create the Input/Output BIO's.                             *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  certbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
  outbio  = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  if(SSL_library_init() < 0)
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Could not initialize the OpenSSL library !\n");

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  method = SSLv23_client_method();

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  if ( (ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method)) == NULL)
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Unable to create a new SSL context structure.\n");

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * Disabling SSLv2 will leave v3 and TSLv1 for negotiation    *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  server = create_socket(dest_url, outbio);
  if(server != 0)
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Successfully made the TCP connection to: %s.\n", dest_url);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  if ( SSL_connect(ssl) != 1 )
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Error: Could not build a SSL session to: %s.\n", dest_url);
  else
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Successfully enabled SSL/TLS session to: %s.\n", dest_url);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
  if (cert == NULL)
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Error: Could not get a certificate from: %s.\n", dest_url);
  else
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Retrieved the server's certificate from: %s.\n", dest_url);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * -----------------------------------------------------------*/
  certname = X509_NAME_new();
  certname = X509_get_subject_name(cert);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * display the cert subject here                              *
   * -----------------------------------------------------------*/
  BIO_printf(outbio, "Displaying the certificate subject data:\n");
  X509_NAME_print_ex(outbio, certname, 0, 0);
  BIO_printf(outbio, "\n");

    /*----------------------------Send-----------------------------------*/

      char buf[5120];

      char *yql =  "GET /v1/public/yql?q HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:query.yahooapis.com";



      printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));

      int result = SSL_write(ssl, yql, strlen(yql));   /* encrypt & send message */
       printf("Result = %i\n",result);
      int  bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get reply & decrypt */

        printf("ReceivedLength: \"%i\"\n", bytes);
        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);



    /*----------------------------End sending-----------------------------------*/
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * -----------------------------------------------------------*/
  SSL_free(ssl);
  close(server);
  X509_free(cert);
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
  BIO_printf(outbio, "Finished SSL/TLS connection with server: %s.\n", dest_url);
  return(0);
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
 * create_socket() creates the socket & TCP-connect to server *
 * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
int create_socket(char url_str[], BIO *out) {
  int sockfd;
  char hostname[256] = "";
  char    portnum[6] = "443";
  char      proto[6] = "";
  char      *tmp_ptr = NULL;
  int           port;
  struct hostent *host;
  struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  if(url_str[strlen(url_str)] == '/')
    url_str[strlen(url_str)] = '\0';

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  strncpy(proto, url_str, (strchr(url_str, ':')-url_str));

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  strncpy(hostname, strstr(url_str, "://")+3, sizeof(hostname));

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  if(strchr(hostname, ':')) {
    tmp_ptr = strchr(hostname, ':');
    /* the last : starts the port number, if avail, i.e. 8443 */
    strncpy(portnum, tmp_ptr+1,  sizeof(portnum));
    *tmp_ptr = '\0';
  }

  port = atoi(portnum);

  if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL ) {
    BIO_printf(out, "Error: Cannot resolve hostname %s.\n",  hostname);
    abort();
  }

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  dest_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  dest_addr.sin_port=htons(port);
  dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  memset(&(dest_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

  tmp_ptr = inet_ntoa(dest_addr.sin_addr);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *

   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  if ( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &dest_addr,
                              sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1 ) {
    BIO_printf(out, "Error: Cannot connect to host %s [%s] on port %d.\n",
             hostname, tmp_ptr, port);
  }

  return sockfd;
}
```

This line  delays and  returns  0 bytes .However sending the same data  through **openssl s_client** gives me the expected result . (***openssl s_client -connect query.yahooapis.com:443 -tls1_2***)

```
 int  bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Expected  Result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:lang="en-US"><description>You must specify a yql statement (q=) to execute</description></error>
```

That  is the output :

```
[root@localhost tlssamples]# ./sslconnect 
Successfully made the TCP connection to: https://query.yahooapis.com.
Successfully enabled SSL/TLS session to: https://query.yahooapis.com.
Retrieved the server's certificate from: https://query.yahooapis.com.
Displaying the certificate subject data:
C=US, ST=CA, L=Sunnyvale, O=Yahoo! Inc., CN=*.ue.yahoo.com
Connected with ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 encryption
Result = 55
ReceivedLength: "0"
Received: ""
Finished SSL/TLS connection with server: https://query.yahooapis.com.
```

Comment: I didn't examine the code much, but shouldn't your http header end with [two new lines](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) (`"\r\n\r\n"`)? Right now you didn't end with even a single newline.

Comment: Yes, the request needs to terminate its HTTP headers with `\r\n\r\n`. It should also have a `Content-Length: 0` header, too. `char *yql =  "GET /v1/public/yql?q HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: query.yahooapis.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";` Since the request is not being sent correctly, the server is likely timing out and closing the connection. That would account for why `SSL_read()` is returning 0 (but use `SSL_get_error()` to confirm. It will likely return `SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN`: "The TLS/SSL connection has been closed")

Comment: @RemyLebeau I Submit Your changes  and get Bad Request 
Result = 79
ReceivedLength: "1489"
Received: "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2018 07:40:30 GMT
Age: 0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Via: http/1.1 a14.ue.bf1.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])
Server: ATS
Finished SSL/TLS connection with server:

Comment: SSL_get_error() catched  : SSL_ERROR_NONE  
Maybe there is  a problem with encryption  of data ?

Comment: @Freeedy no, the encryption is working fine, by virtue of the fact that you are able to get a valid HTTP response from Yahoo at all. The problem is in your HTTP request. You are likely not sending everything that Yahoo requires. Like OAuth authentication, for instance

Comment: Solution is  here . 
https://github.com/Freeedy/sslClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in here .

usage :

```
./sslClient raw.githubusercontent.com 443 "/yql/yql-tables/master/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.quotes.xml"
```

https://github.com/Freeedy/sslClient.git